# How to pass parameters do a call to Logger.info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method like:

```
def test(p1, p2)
   logger.info 'calling test with p1=' + p1 + ' p2 = ' + p2
end
```

Getting a cast error, how should I be doing this neatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cast error is probably because p1 or p2 is not a string type.  Ruby's string interpolation will handle this for you:

```
def test(p1, p2)
  logger.info "calling test with p1=#{p1} p2=#{p2}"
end
```

Here's how it works: ruby calls `to_s` on any variables in the string (denoted by `#{}`) which converts them to a string.  Every object in ruby has this method, so you don't need to worry about it from there.  I hope this helps!

**UPDATE:** This was a simple, but interesting question because there's more to it than meets the eye (like transformers).  The way Ruby does this actually opens the door to functionality you can use in your own classes.  I turned the answer into a blog post with code samples and a more detailed explanation:

[Ruby String Interpolation](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/08/ruby-string-interpolation/)